# open62541 nodeset_compiler failing to compile

Tags: opc-ua

I am trying to compile the EUROMAP 82.3 standard using the open62541 nodeset_compiler.

I do this command in my Commandprompt:

> PS C:\Users\User\Downloads\open62541-pack-v1.3.9\open62541-pack-v1.3.9\tools\nodeset_compiler> python ./nodeset_compiler.py --types-array=UA_TYPES --existing ../../deps/ua-nodeset/Schema/Opc.Ua.NodeSet2.xml --xml Opc.Ua.PlasticsRubber.LDS.NodeSet2.xml myNS

This is the result:

> INFO:**main**:Preprocessing (existing) ../../deps/ua-nodeset/Schema/Opc.Ua.NodeSet2.xml
> INFO:**main**:Preprocessing Opc.Ua.PlasticsRubber.LDS.NodeSet2.xml
> ['http://opcfoundation.org/UA/', 'http://opcfoundation.org/UA/PlasticsRubber/LDS/', 'http://opcfoundation.org/UA/PlasticsRubber/GeneralTypes/', 'http://opcfoundation.org/UA/DI/']
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\User\Downloads\open62541-pack-v1.3.9\open62541-pack-v1.3.9\tools\User\nodeset_compiler.py", line 168, in 
> ns.sanitize()
> File "C:\Users\NickdeBoerMovacolor\Downloads\open62541-pack-v1.3.9\open62541-pack-v1.3.9\tools\nodeset_compiler\nodeset.py", line 137, in sanitize
> raise Exception("Reference " + str(ref) + " has an unknown target")
> Exception: Reference ns=1;i=5001--[ns=0;i=40]-->ns=2;i=1057 has an unknown target
> PS C:\Users\User\Downloads\open62541-pack-v1.3.9\open62541-pack-v1.3.9\tools\nodeset_compiler>

Now i understand t cant find the target 1057, i found this node id in "../../deps/ua-nodeset/Scales/Opc.Ua.Scales.NodeSet2.xml" but i have no idea what i am doing wrong and why i cant compile.